# How to assign json file's content to a variable using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I trying to run below PowerShell script to add azure data factory data sets. But im getting motioned error.
**Json File**

```
{
    "name": "DSNAME",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "REGNAME1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureDataExplorerTable",
        "schema": [],
        "typeProperties": {
            "table": "TABLE_TEST"
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

**Powershell**

```
az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt
Get-ChildItem "ADF_DATASETS/" -Filter *.json | 
Foreach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName

az datafactory dataset create --properties $content --name "DATASETNAME" --factory-name "ADFNAME" --resource-group "RG_TEST"

}
```

**Error:**
Error detail: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
Please provide a valid JSON file path or JSON string.
The provided JSON string may have been parsed by the shell. See https://docs.microsoft.com/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively#use-quotation-marks-in-arguments
ERROR: Failed to parse string as JSON:

Comment: Have you tried converting $content to json. ConvertTo-Json might help.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of text `--properties` expect?

It is expecting JSON string in double quotation [marks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/datafactory/dataset?view=azure-cli-latest#az-datafactory-dataset-create). So you have to put the value of `$content` inside the double quotation mark.

```
az datafactory dataset create --properties "{\"type\":\"AzureBlob\",\"linkedServiceName\":{\"type\":\"LinkedServiceReference\",\"referenceName\":\"exampleLinkedService\"},\"parameters\":{\"MyFileName\":{\"type\":\"String\"},\"MyFolderPath\":{\"type\":\"String\"}},\"typeProperties\":{\"format\":{\"type\":\"TextFormat\"},\"fileName\":{\"type\":\"Expression\",\"value\":\"@dataset().MyFileName\"},\"folderPath\":{\"type\":\"Expression\",\"value\":\"@dataset().MyFolderPath\"}}}" --name "exampleDataset" --factory-name "exampleFactoryName" --resource-group "exampleResourceGroup"
```

Comment: --properties expect name of the json file inside the ADF_DATASETS/ location.

Comment: but Get-Content is giving you the content of the file, not the name. Have you tried without Get-Content?